# What is the process for converting a US certificate to a Japanese license?

Tags: regulations, japan

I have a Japanese exchange student (here for at least 4 years) who is looking to pursue a pilot's certificate (up through commercial, potentially to an ATP rating) in the US and, upon returning to Japan, convert it into Japanese ratings and licenses and try to get into the airlines.

I'm trying to give him an idea of how difficult or not it is to make that happen, and what hoops he might need to jump through.  Google has only led me to outdated forums and websites, so I thought I'd give it a go here.

**How do you convert a given US pilot's certificate (private pilot, commercial, ATP and ratings including instrument, etc.) to a Japanese license?**

Comment: This page may be helpful from AOPA Japan: http://www.aopa.jp/Newenglish/Newenglish/Fly_1%20rev%202.html